# gdb in Emacs: how to enable the readline features?

Tags: emacs, gdb, readline

After call `M-x gdb`, I started the debugging process. However, the following contents in my `.inputrc` is not respected by Emacs:

```
"\C-p":history-search-backward
"\C-n":history-search-forward
```

How can I fix this, so I can search history faster in the GDB console in Emacs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When running GDB inside Emacs, the readline interface is not used.  Instead, the interface is an Emacs mode called [Comint](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ComintMode), which stands for "command interpreter" and is a generic mode for running interactive programs.  That's why it doesn't pick up the contents of `.inputrc`, which is a readline configuration file.

In Comint mode, you can search the command history with `M-r`, which is bound to `comint-history-isearch-backward-regexp`.  It works like isearch: type a search string, and then hit `C-r` and `C-s` to go to the previous or next match, respectively.